# AOC 931s monitor is dark at the top and bright at the bottom - should I return it?

Tags: display

I just got a AOC 931s monitor, but I have a problem.

When I look at the monitor straight from the front, it's dark at the top and bright at the bottom.

Does this mean there's a production error with the device?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like one of the backlights has failed - the top one specifically. Its been known to happen, but unfortunately its not one of the easier things to troubleshoot - you'd have to open up the entire lcd panel if you were to replace it.

If its a new monitor, and covered under a warranty, i seriously suggest taking advantage of it and getting it replaced.